# How do you find if the given pair of vectors are parallel?

Tags: linear-algebra, complex-numbers

$[1 + i, i, 1 - i], [1-i, 1, -1-i]$ ?

Solution:

Parallel because $[1+i, i, 1 -i] = i[1 - i, 1, -1-i]$

how did they know to divide by i?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If two vectors are parallel, then one is a scalar multiple of the other. In your case we'd have
$$
[1+i, i, 1-i]=k[1-i,1, -1-i]
$$
so we have three equations:
$$\begin{align}
1+i&=k(1-i) & (1)\\
i &= k\cdot1 & (2)\\
1-i&=k(-1-i) & (3)
\end{align}$$
and so (2) gives us $k=i$ which is consistent with the other two equations.

Answer (score 0):

Two vectors $v$ and $u$ are parallel if for some number $a$ we have $v = a \times u$.

So if you want to find out whether $v$ and $u$ are parellel you need to find such a number. In the complex plane

$$i = 0 + 1i$$

is that $a$.

Given how your question is written, I think you understand this and are asking how they were able to arrive at the answer $i$. For simple questions like this I think most would just guess and see if it works. However you could solve the simultaneous questions:

$$(1+i) = a \times (1-i)$$

$$i = a \times 1$$

$$a(-1-i) = 1 \times -i$$

Which are obtained by simply looking at each of the three elements of the vectors. By looking at equation 2

$$i = a \times 1$$

It follows immediately that the only solution is $a = i$.